# Retrieving total count of bugs based on custom search

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

I am trying to retrieve the count of issues in a project which are bugs and whose status has been closed or resolved and resolution fixed. Along with that I am trying to make sure the assignee of the bug is not same as the reporter or the assignee is not unassigned.

This is what I have so far:

```
https://issues.apache.org/jira/rest/api/2/search?jql=issuetype=Bug and resolution=Fixed and status= Resolved or status = Closed and project=AMQ and assignee!=reporter and assignee != ''
```

However, the total count returned is more than the actual count of bugs present in the project repository. Please assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to filter with `assignee!=reporter` as you try in your API call. Furthermore, you would have to use `assignee is NOT EMPTY` instead of `assignee != ''` to get the issues without an assignee. Lastly, you need to put parentheses around `(status=Resolved or status=Closed)` to not walk into an OR-trap.

If you use python with [python-jira](https://jira.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html), the code to get your desired result would be like this:

```
# connect to your JIRA instance
jira = JIRA('https://issues.apache.org/')

# get the issues via API search
issues = jira.search_issues("issuetype=Bug AND resolution=Fixed AND (status=Resolved or status=Closed) AND project=AMQ AND assignee is NOT EMPTY")

filtered_issues = [] # this variable will hold the correct list of issues

# filter the tickets where assignee != reporter
for issue in issues:

    # to prevent AttributeError due to possible NoneType
    try:
        reporter = issue.fields.reporter.key
    except AttributeError:
        reporter = ""

    # to prevent AttributeError due to possible NoneType
    try:
        assignee = issue.fields.assignee.key
    except AttributeError:
        assignee = ""

    if reporter != assignee:
        filtered_issues.append(issue)

print(filtered_issues) # list of issues
print(len(filtered_issues)) # number of issues
```